# PDF to XML conversion using PDFX http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/

Tags: python, xml, pdf

I'm aware that PDFX is a rule-based system designed to reconstruct the logical structure of scholarly articles in PDF form, regardless of their formatting style. The system's output is an XML document that describes the input article's logical structure in terms of title, sections, tables, references, etc.

I've been trying to convert some PDF files into XML using PDFX on python but http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/ is not responding.

The code I use for the conversion is:

`response = requests.post('http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/', headers=headers, data=data)`

Is it still available? Is there any other option to convert the documents reconstructing the structure of scholarly articles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the research I've been doing this days, I could find a similar tool called GROBID.

Home page: https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

GitHub: https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid

Is a machine learning software for extracting information from scholarly documents